# SOAPUI - is it possible to use DataSource Loop on multiple test steps?

Tags: soapui, testcase, test-suite

When creating automatic tests in SOAPUI is it possible to configure a loop which will run more than 1 test steps in a test case?
I have a following structure:

TestSuite -> TestCase -> Test Steps:

- DataSource
- TestRequest1
- GroovyScript1
- TestRequest
- GroovyScript
- DataSource Loop

and I want to run all test steps with all the data from my DataSource.

In TestSource Loop configuration it is only possible to chose DataSource step and Target Step (only 1 test step). So, how can I loop through all the steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Target Step is where each iteration will **begin**! It will run everything after the step you name.

Comment: If you like the answer, please click to "accept" it.